# Problem with Time Interrupts in ESP8266 with water proof depth sensor

Tags: esp8266, sensors, esp

I am trying to use an edited version of waterproof depth sensor code from the Arduino blog. It works well on my Arduino Uno board; however, it doesn't work with my ESP8266 board. Is there a way to adjust it? I understand that the problem is with Arduino clock module and time interrupts. On the other hand, I can't know where to find their counterparts in the ESP libraries.
Code is here:

```
#include <SPI.h>
const int clock = 4;
float initial = 0;
void resetsensor() 
{
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0); 
  SPI.transfer(0x15);
  SPI.transfer(0x55);
  SPI.transfer(0x40);
}
float read_pressure(){
  TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0xF8) | 1 ; //generates the MCKL signal
  analogWrite (clock, 128) ; 
  resetsensor(); 
  unsigned int result1 = 0;
  unsigned int inbyte1 = 0;
  SPI.transfer(0x1D); 
  SPI.transfer(0x50); 
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1);
  result1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); 
  result1 = result1 << 8; 
  inbyte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); 
  result1 = result1 | inbyte1; 
  resetsensor();
  unsigned int result2 = 0;
  byte inbyte2 = 0; 
  SPI.transfer(0x1D);
  SPI.transfer(0x60);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); 
  result2 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  result2 = result2 <<8;
  inbyte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  result2 = result2 | inbyte2;
  resetsensor();
  unsigned int result3 = 0;
  byte inbyte3 = 0;
  SPI.transfer(0x1D);
  SPI.transfer(0x90); 
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); 
  result3 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  result3 = result3 <<8;
  inbyte3 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  result3 = result3 | inbyte3;
  resetsensor();
  unsigned int result4 = 0;
  byte inbyte4 = 0;
  SPI.transfer(0x1D);
  SPI.transfer(0xA0);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); 
  result4 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  result4 = result4 <<8;
  inbyte4 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  result4 = result4 | inbyte4;
  long c1 = (result1 >> 1) & 0x7FFF;
  long c2 = ((result3 & 0x003F) << 6) | (result4 & 0x003F);
  long c3 = (result4 >> 6) & 0x03FF;
  long c4 = (result3 >> 6) & 0x03FF;
  long c5 = ((result1 & 0x0001) << 10) | ((result2 >> 6) & 0x03FF);
  long c6 = result2 & 0x003F;
  resetsensor();
  unsigned int presMSB = 0; //first byte of value
  unsigned int presLSB = 0; //last byte of value
  unsigned int D1 = 0;
  SPI.transfer(0x0F); //send first byte of command to get pressure value
  SPI.transfer(0x40); //send second byte of command to get pressure value
  delay(35); //wait for conversion end
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); //change mode in order to listen
  presMSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read first byte of value
  presMSB = presMSB << 8; //shift first byte
  presLSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read second byte of value
  D1 = presMSB | presLSB; //combine first and second byte of value
  resetsensor(); //resets the sensor  
  unsigned int tempMSB = 0; //first byte of value
  unsigned int tempLSB = 0; //last byte of value
  unsigned int D2 = 0;
  SPI.transfer(0x0F); //send first byte of command to get temperature value
  SPI.transfer(0x20); //send second byte of command to get temperature value
  delay(35); //wait for conversion end
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); //change mode in order to listen
  tempMSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read first byte of value
  tempMSB = tempMSB << 8; //shift first byte
  tempLSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read second byte of value
  D2 = tempMSB | tempLSB; //combine first and second byte of value
  const long UT1 = (c5 << 3) + 20224;
  const long dT = D2 - UT1;
  const long TEMP = 200 + ((dT * (c6 + 50)) >> 10);
  const long OFF  = (c2 * 4) + (((c4 - 512) * dT) >> 12);
  const long SENS = c1 + ((c3 * dT) >> 10) + 24576;
  const long X = (SENS * (D1 - 7168) >> 14) - OFF;
  long PCOMP = ((X * 10) >> 5) + 2500;
  float TEMPREAL = TEMP/10;
  float PCOMPHG = PCOMP * 750.06 / 10000; // mbar*10 -> mmHg === ((mbar/10)/1000)*750/06
  long T2 = 0;
  float P2 = 0;
  if (TEMP < 200)
    {
      T2 = (11 * (c6 + 24) * (200 - TEMP) * (200 - TEMP) ) >> 20;
      P2 = (3 * T2 * (PCOMP - 3500) ) >> 14;
    }
  else if (TEMP > 450)
    {
      T2 = (3 * (c6 + 24) * (450 - TEMP) * (450 - TEMP) ) >> 20;
      P2 = (T2 * (PCOMP - 10000) ) >> 13;    
    }
  if ((TEMP < 200) || (TEMP > 450))
  {
    const float TEMP2 = TEMP - T2;
    const float PCOMP2 = PCOMP - P2;
    float TEMPREAL2 = TEMP2/10;
    float PCOMPHG2 = PCOMP2 * 750.06 / 10000; // mbar*10 -> mmHg === ((mbar/10)/1000)*750/06
    return PCOMPHG2;
  }
}
void initialialize()
{
  Serial.print("Setting initial");
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    initial += read_pressure();
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  initial /= 10;
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("initialial Pressure: ");
  Serial.println(initial);
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin(); 
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV32); 
  pinMode(clock, OUTPUT);
  delay(100);
  initialialize();
  delay(5000);
}
void loop() 
{
  float reading = (read_pressure() - initial) * 1.3595474315191;
  Serial.print("Water is: ");
  Serial.print(reading);
  Serial.println("cm");
  delay(500);
}
```

I get errors with both the *clock variable* and *TCCR1B*.